# 3V3 to a Teensy 4.0 pin 4 (BCLK2) for servo PCB troubleshoot

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

[image: PCB routing]

[image: teensy 4.1 microcontroller schematic]
[image: connectors schematic]
[image: bidirectional voltage level converter]

This project interfaces a servo to the teensy 4.0 through a bidirectional voltage level converter. The schematic shows the servo to run on 5V using an encoder. I dont understand why the 3.3V pin on the bidirectional voltage level converter connected to one of the encoder pins.

Additionally, there is two Runcam thumb cameras interfacing with the teensy and I dont understand where i've gone wrong for they won't allow a trace two connect the two pins.

Comment: A circuit diagram would be VERY useful